# css background:cover dont cover the whole screen in mobile view

Tags: html, css, web

I have tried many solutions, but to no avail.

I have issues mainly:

1. why is there a scroll (both horizontally and vertically). it should just fit in the view-port size. i am using `height:100vh`. i have used `meta` tag too.
2. why `background-size:cover` isn't working, also giving scroll in vertical desktop view too.
3. at least the text shouldn't have been cut at all. why is it so?
4. List item

desktop view:
[image: desktop view seems ok.]
mobile view:
[image: half of screen left black, with scroll]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), #009688) , url(Barber_Shop_img/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;   
}


.logo{
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 10%;
}

.banner-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 180px;
    color: white;
}

.banner-text h1{
    font-size: 130px;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.banner-text p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.banner-btn{
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}

/* the tutorial aims to make buttons using anchor tag, and on hover make the background color to white and text color to black */
/* explain position relative and position absolute in this context */
/* explain z-index of -1 and 1 in this code */
/* explain the transition: color 0.5s in this code. because code runs same withotut writing the word 'color' */
.banner-btn a{
    color: white;
    border: .5px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barbar Shop Website Design - Easy Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
     <section id="banner">
        <img class="logo" src="Barber_Shop_img/logo.png">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Hair Studio</h1>
            <p>Style your hair to Style your personality</p>
            <div class="banner-btn">
                <a href="#"> <span></span>Find Out</a>
                <a href="#"> <span></span>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Various dimensions expressed in pixels -- especially large numbers of pixels -- are not very friendly to small screens.

Answer (score 1):

Your background is not image and cover property is nonsense. Please update your code as below and it will work. Good luck

```
#banner {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), #009688), url(Barber_Shop_img/banner.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .banner-text {
    padding: 50px;
  }

  .banner-text h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }

  .banner-text p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Donald, could you tell me what background-size and background-position  are for? The background is not image and these style won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), #009688) , url(Barber_Shop_img/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: center
    height: 100vh;   
}


.logo{
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 4%;
    left: 10%;
}

.banner-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 180px;
    color: white;
}

.banner-text h1{
    font-size: 130px;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.banner-text p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.banner-btn{
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}

/* the tutorial aims to make buttons using anchor tag, and on hover make the background color to white and text color to black */
/* explain position relative and position absolute in this context */
/* explain z-index of -1 and 1 in this code */
/* explain the transition: color 0.5s in this code. because code runs same withotut writing the word 'color' */
.banner-btn a{
    color: white;
    border: .5px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barbar Shop Website Design - Easy Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
     <section id="banner">
        <img class="logo" src="Barber_Shop_img/logo.png">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <h1>Hair Studio</h1>
            <p>Style your hair to Style your personality</p>
            <div class="banner-btn">
                <a href="#"> <span></span>Find Out</a>
                <a href="#"> <span></span>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a fixed full-height background which works on all devices, use a separate `<div>` styled with `position: fixed`.

For large headings you might find that `vw` units are good for setting the font size.

```
.banner-text h1 {
    font-size: 15vw;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.fixed-background {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), #009688) , url(http://picsum.photos/800);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
    width: 10vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 10%;
}

.banner-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10vw;
    color: white;
}

.banner-text h1 {
    font-size: 15vw;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
.banner-text p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.banner-btn {
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}

.banner-btn a {
    color: white;
    border: .5px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="fixed-background"></div>

<section id="banner">
  <img class="logo" src="http://picsum.photos/300">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1>Hair Studio</h1>
    <p>Style your hair to Style your personality</p>
    <div class="banner-btn">
      <a href="#"> <span></span>Find Out</a>
      <a href="#"> <span></span>Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem simply in this line

```
.banner-text h1{
font-size: 130px; }
```

in mobile this line will make the h1 element overflow the container

so you must choose less font-size in mobile view

or you can add to .banner-text div

```
overflow:hidden;
```

but part of the text in h1 will be hidden

or you can add

```
overflow:auto
```

then a scroll bar will appear to show all the text in h1

also this line

```
.banner-text {
padding: 180px; }
```

this is huge padding on mobile, you must reduce it and use also

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

finally if you want to make responsive design start to learn bootstrap or media queries

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp